# Unix protocol not supported - Docker Plugin Version - 0.16.2

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

When I try to connect my Jenkins to docker using docker plugin's latest version , it does not connect !

**ERROR - "org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: unix protocol is not supported (show details)"** using unix:///var/run/docker.sock command (as provided in their help tag - shocked to see that) !

But this doesn't happen when I downgrade the version to 0.16.1 and it connects with the above command !

Please Help regarding the latest version as to what should I type in "Docker URL" in docker cloud section of Jenkins configuration.